# What is the purpose of the backup user installed by default?

Tags: 12.04, backup, users, default

from /etc/passwd:

```
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/bin/sh
```

The home directory listed is /var/backups which is owned by root:root. Here are the contents of the home directory:

```
total 4.1M
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4.0K May 29 11:17 ./
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root   4.0K May 28 00:32 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    11K May 28 20:16 apt.extended_states.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1.4K Apr 28 16:50 apt.extended_states.1.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1.2K Apr 14 21:06 apt.extended_states.2.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1.1K Apr  7 13:45 apt.extended_states.3.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1.1K Mar 28 22:00 apt.extended_states.4.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1.1K Mar 18 22:26 apt.extended_states.5.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    970 Mar 14 23:52 apt.extended_states.6.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1.6M May 28 20:16 dpkg.status.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   432K May 27 23:04 dpkg.status.1.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   431K Apr 28 16:50 dpkg.status.2.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   426K Apr 14 21:06 dpkg.status.3.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   420K Apr  7 13:45 dpkg.status.4.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   418K Mar 28 22:00 dpkg.status.5.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   416K Mar 20 21:08 dpkg.status.6.gz
-rw-------  1 root root    918 May 28 20:12 group.bak
-rw-------  1 root shadow  758 May 28 20:12 gshadow.bak
-rw-------  1 root root   1.8K May 28 20:12 passwd.bak
-rw-------  1 root shadow 1.2K May 28 20:12 shadow.bak
```

Obviously, these are backup files of some sort but which process is creating them? I did a quick find to see if this user owned anything but it didn't turn up much:

```
$ sudo find / -user backup
/var/mail/backup
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty consistent with what I see in the same directory. I don't know what process(es) are creating them per se, but most  of them are related to `apt` and `dpkg` lists of installed files and apps. I'd leave it alone and not worry - just the system doing its' thing.

Comment: Created by cron scripts, see ````grep -R backups /etc/cron.daily````